# Send data through form post and get a different output

Tags: php, forms, post, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to sign some data with `RSA` encryption, but when I send the data through the form it somehow changes the data and it's not functioning, my script takes data and generates a digital signature, I'm trying to send that signature through form and verify the data with it, it works before I send it to form, but doesn't work after, here is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<style media="screen">
body{
padding:60px;
background: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(array_search("",$_POST)){
$config = array(
                   "digest_alg" => "sha256",
                     "private_key_bits" => 4096,
                     "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
                   );
                   // Create the private and public key
                   $result = openssl_pkey_new( $config );
                   // Extract the private key from $result to $privKey
                   openssl_pkey_export( $result, $privKey );
                   // Extract the public key from $result to $pubKey
                   $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details( $result );
                   $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];
openssl_sign('hello',$signature,$privKey);
echo  openssl_verify('hello',$signature,$pubKey);
}
else{
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
echo "we got ".$key." : ".$value."<br><br><br>"; }
echo  openssl_verify($_POST['data'],$_POST['signature'],$_POST['pubKey']);
}
                  ?>

<form  action="#" method="post" id="test">
<input type="text" name="data" value="hello">
<textarea name="signature" rows="8" cols="80" form="test"><?php 
if(isset($signature)){echo $signature;}?></textarea>
<textarea name="privKey" rows="8" cols="80" form="test"><?php 
if(isset($privKey)){echo $privKey;}?></textarea>
<textarea name="pubKey" rows="8" cols="80" form="test"><?php 
if(isset($pubKey)){echo $pubKey;}?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? "Doesn't work after" is not very descriptive.

Comment: I'm sorry for that lack of explanation, what I meant by it doesn't work is that the 

     echo  openssl_verify('hello',$signature,$pubKey);

 when the variables are just created and it returns true, but it returns false when that same information are posted and 

    echo openssl_verify($_POST['data'],$_POST['signature'],
$_POST['pubKey']); 

returns false